# How to stop HTTP ERROR status code 404 when loading CSS file

Tags: html, css

I've started using visual studio code and live server to practice making websites and the main.css file is not loading with the index.html.

when using the the devtools it appears it's an old version the main.css as the changes I've made aren't showing!

The exact message that comes up is "Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:5500/CSS/main.scss (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)"

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/main.css">
```

The above is the code I've used, I've tried having the css and html in the same folder, in different folders and have made sure I'm selecting the correct file path as when going to type it in it shows and gives the option to autofill instead of typing it all out.

Comment: A 404 error means that the server can't find a file the browser is asking for.  You should ensure the file `<web-root>/CSS/main.scss` exists, and is readable.

Comment: It might help to know what web server you're using.

Comment: I'm just using live server with visual studio code

Answer (score -1):

Your url is showing `.scss` but browser doesn't understand `scss` or `sass`

To fix this:

1. First restart live sass compiler
2. Make any random change like remove and add a semicolon in your main.scss and save it.
   This will recompile the whole main.scss and you will have the updated file.

IF the issue still persists then do this:

Try this:

1. Stop the live server.
2. Close all the other files in the editor and first only open `Index.html`
3. Right click and click on Open with live server.

It will automatically load all your other files.

Comment: I've tried this and its still not working unfortunately

Comment: can you please send your directory structure in vs code? screenshot